# How can I programmatically convert Greek symbols to lowercase in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

A simple task: I require a user-defined command `\greeklower` that accepts any Greek character recognized by math mode and returns the lowercase version of the character.

Ideally the command syntax would be e.g. `\greeklower{\Phi}` and `\greeklower{\phi}` both expanding to `\phi`, `\greeklower{\Gamma}` and `\greeklower{\gamma}` both expanding to `\gamma`, etc.

However, the syntax `\greeklower{Phi}`, `\greeklower{phi}` is also acceptable.

I have attempted the following:

`\lowercase{\Gamma}`: does nothing

`\MakeLowercase{\Gamma}`: does nothing

`\newcommand {\greeklower} [1] {\expandafter\csname\lowercase{#1}\endcsname}`: "error: missing \endcsname"

`\newcommand {\greeklower} [1] {\expandafter\csname\MakeLowercase{#1}\endcsname}`: "error: missing \endcsname"

```
\edef\elower#1{\lowercase{#1}}
\newcommand {\greeklower} [1] {\expandafter\csname\elower{#1}\endcsname}
```

"error: missing \endcsname"

```
\edef\elower#1{\MakeLowercase{#1}}
\newcommand {\greeklower} [1] {\expandafter\csname\elower{#1}\endcsname}
```

"error: TeX capacity exceeded"

Hence once again TeX has defeated me. :(

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand {\greeklower} [1] { -make Greek symbol lowercase- }

\begin{document}
This is a $\gamma$ tensor: $\boldsymbol{\greeklower{\Gamma}}$.

This is also a $\gamma$ tensor: $\boldsymbol{\greeklower{\gamma}}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: why lowercase in *math* mode? That doesn't make much sense, lower casing is something that should affect text.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I have an equivalence between matrix operators and type-(1,1) tensors in the document I'm writing. The convention in the working domain is that the tensors use lowercase versions of the symbols used for the operators, whose characters are fungible to a degree and can be Greek symbols.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just redefine *locally* the uppercase Greek characters to become their lowercase counterparts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\LowerGreek}[1]{\begingroup
\let\Gamma\gamma
\let\Delta\delta
\let\VarTheta\vartheta
\let\Lambda\lamda
\let\Theta\theta
\let\Pi\pi
\let\Sigma\sigma
\let\Upsilon\upsilon
\let\Phi\phi
\let\Psi\psi
\let\Omega\omega
#1
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
This is a $\gamma$ tensor: $\boldsymbol{\LowerGreek{\Gamma}}$ but $\Gamma$ still
works.

This is also a $\gamma$ tensor: $\boldsymbol{\LowerGreek{\gamma}}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hm. Crude... but it works. Thanks. :)

Comment: @COTO You're welcome! (I am always excited to meet other cats. ;-)